# what is cc_pp3_data table in XCart's database?

Tags: payment-gateway, x-cart

I'm trying to write a payment module for XCart 4.4.4 .
There is a `cc_pp3_data` table in DB that all of other payment modules run this query on it:

```
    db_query("REPLACE INTO $sql_tbl[cc_pp3_data] (ref,sessionid, param1) VALUES ('".addslashes($_orderids)."','".$XCARTSESSID."', '$md5_orig')");
```

What is this table for?

Answer (score 0):

This table is served for saving temporary order data. After payment gateway redirected a  customer back to X-Cart site (or when payment gateway issued a callback) X-Cart can detect if received request is related to a real order by extracting some data from cc_pp3_data. This table is used for web-based payment modules and web-based modules with callback.